# Setting focus gives the button focus, but focus is not visible

Tags: angular, focus

In an angular solution, I have some dialogs located in <div's>.

Open them like:

```
    this.deleteFileDialogOpened=true;
    setTimeout(() => { 
      this.btnOk2.nativeElement.focus(); 
    }, 10);
```

where

```
  @ViewChild('msgOkBtn2') btnOk2: ElementRef;
```

The button gets focus, but focus is not visible. Space works as I want it to.
Pressing tab-key moved to the next (cancel) button, and the button has "a focus ring", clearly showing it has focus. Shift+tab and it goes back, same way, focus is visible.

Is there a way to make focus visible? Like when moving with the tab key, so I can actually see where focus is.

I could change it CSS, but is there a "system way" to do this?
Even standard buttons have this issue.

The dialog is as simple as it gets:

```
<div *ngIf="deleteFileDialogOpened" class="....">
    <div>
        <p>Do you want to the delete the file {{filenameToDelete}}?</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button (click)="deleteFile()" #msgOkBtn2>Yes</button>
        <button (click)="closeDialog()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

:focus focuses the element, but does not necessarily :focus-visible - the visible part. You should edit :focus-visible of your element or go with the css option. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible

Css option demo here (on which also component has :focus-visible): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzf4pd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: I tried that and I can do some stuff there. Now I see that odd thing is, that the button has focus so space key will make it click. However, the css state focus-visible is not entered by setting focus, but by going there manually. 
So using tab key gives it the css state too. Just appointing focus from code does not

Comment: Do not focus on nativeElement, `.focus()` on HTMLElement. If you are using `.focus()` make sure to run it in `ngAfterViewInit ` the earliest. HTMLElement needs to be rendered on DOM before it can be focused.